# System.Drawing.Color named Highlight? What is it? For WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing.color

I have a WinForm application where this C# code assigns color:

```
grid.Styles.Highlight.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.TrueDBGridSelectedStyleBackColor;
```

If I look up where it's defined, I find it in Settings.settings defined like so:

```
<Setting Name="C1TabPageTabBackColorSelected" Type="System.Drawing.Color" Scope="Application">
  <Value Profile="(Default)">Highlight</Value>
</Setting>
```

Note the word **Highlight** there. Other colors in this file are defined with a color name or with rgb values, but what does Highlight mean?

If I stop in the debugger on the C# code that assigns it and look at

```
Properties.Settings.Default.TrueDBGridSelectedStyleBackColor
```

I see "{Name=Highlight, ARGB=(255, 0, 120, 215)}"   System.Drawing.Color

If I assign the same color in ARGB instead like so:

```
grid.Styles.Highlight.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 120, 215);
```

I get a different color - much darker blue with no red component in the resulting control.

There is no Color.HighLight constant like there is Color.White for example.
What's going on here?
Is there some special behaviour for the color named Highlight?

Does it get a color originally from say some OS colors, but gets overwritten by control because of the name? I can't find any doc saying so.

Comment: It is a [KnownColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.knowncolor?view=net-6.0).  Yes, specifically the color used to highlight selected text, typically blue.  Values less than 27 on that page are theme colors, back in the good old days they were easy to change by the user.  Google "windows hot dog stand" to see how that could get out of hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably the [SystemColors.Highlight Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemcolors.highlight?view=net-6.0). It does not refer to a specific color but to the highlight color of the current Windows theme used for the background of the selected item, e.g. in a listbox.

As @HansPassant pointed out, `Highlight` is also one the [KnownColor Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.knowncolor?view=net-6.0) constants. You can use the [Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor?view=net-6.0) to get the color corresponding to one of these enum constants.